estimation of multivariate probability
Let $(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})$ be a multivariate distribution and I can generate the sample from it. Next, assume that I have to compute
$$
P(X_{1}\in A_{1}, \dots, X_{n}\in A_{n}),
$$
where $A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}$ are some intervals. Then, the natural way to do this is to estimate it from samples $(x_{1}^{i}, \dots, x_{n}^{i})$ where $i = 1:N$
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}I\{ x_{1}^{i}\in A_{1}, \dots, x^{i}_{n}\in A_{n})\}}{N}.
$$
For which distributions it would be a bad method? In which cases it could be better to take numerically integral, if the joint distribution can be written?
